# can't perform show() method in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something like:

```
<div id="id1">
    //some code 1

    <div id = "id2">
    //some code 2

    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I hide the all block with the command :

```
$("#id1").hide();
```

But, when I'm trying to show the inner block, with the command:

```
$("#id2").show();
```

But this doesn't work!

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

When parent element is *hidden* , all its children are *hidden* too.

If you want to show only the element with '`id2`' id, you can do it like this:

```
$('#id1').children(':not(#id2)').hide();  //Hiding all children except '#id2'  
$('#id1').show();
```

Comment: How can i overcome this problem? if i want that only the child be shown?

Comment: @AlexanderPalvanov - In a nutshell, Make `<div />` siblings, hide both, show one. Use a same call to hide both of them easily

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, I have forgotten to add ':' sign before 'not'.

Comment: @AlexanderPalvanov See my recent comment.

Comment: @Engineer Thanks it's working, but causes other problems in my program :)

Comment: @mplungjan yeah, i know, that my code does not hide text nodes.But probably this doesn't neccessary for the OP.

Comment: @AlexanderPalvanov And what problems?

Comment: @Engineer I have a login-logout system that i'm trying to do, and now with this command, some other functions that need to show some other blocks don't work. It's hard to explain here, but thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderPalvanov It's really hard to help you, without seeing your actual code.

Comment: @Engineer It's okay, i did my adjustments, based on your code, and now it's works (not the best performance though) :)

Answer (score 4):

If `id1` is hidden, it doesn't matter whether `id2` is visible or not. It won't be shown because its parent is hidden. This is true for all descendent elements.

Answer (score 1):

**No this isn't possible using `display:none`** (which is what `.hide()` does). `display:none` hides the element, and thus any child elements will not be displayed.

This might be along the lines of what you want, if you're able to switch from using `display` to `visibility`.

```
#id1 {visibility: hidden;}
#id2 {visibility: visible;}
```

Check out the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vLYnk/2/

With javascript you could use:

```
$("#id1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
$("#id2").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Comment: But the hidden stuff still takes up space. I reverted my -1 because it does show the stuff

Comment: @mplungjan: I guess it doesn't take up space, thats the default line-height. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/vLYnk/4/

Comment: Hi, its working but not perfect, it still shows things like background that it shouldn't show. e.g when you have grand children

Answer (score 0):

create an element and copy it then show it.

```
var element = jQuery('#id2').clone();
element.appendTo('some element');
```

Comment: `clone()` is quite cpu-intensive and slower than the other answers provided which use `hide()/show()`

Answer (score -2):

you need to move the inner div out if you want to show it. somthing like

```
$("#id2").parents(":visible").appendTo($("#id2"))
```

Comment: so im the only one comming whith a possible solution. and im getting downvoted?

Comment: No, you are getting downvoted because the solution is incorrect. Moving the div out may not be what he wants

Comment: What if he has a style whose selector is something like `#id1 #id2`